# Database replication with ability to revert to previous states

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to setup a development database such that it'll initially be a mirror of the database used in production.  At fixed points during the day (maybe midnight or something) and/or manually, I want it to be sync'd once again with the production DB.

My goal is to have a database I can play and mess with, with no lasting consequences.  I've looked at replication, and it doesn't seem to be a good fit for this scenario.  See, what I thought initially is that I could set up a slave, dump it, do my work, then use the dump to revert it to its previous (pristine?) state, before syncing with the master.  Repeat when needed.  While I might be able to get away with this with relatively small DBs, 8 gigs worth of dumps tend to take a while to be generated and imported.  Plus I'd like to be able to have something that will scale to several devs.

Any hints as to where I should look next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look into MySQL snapshots using the file system. More details in [this link](http://forge.mysql.com/w/images/c/c1/MySQL_Backups_using_File_System_Snapshots-2009-02-26.pdf). Snapshots are very quick to create, and can be rolled back to.

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle it's quite easy, a snapshot standby database would do the trick for you. Maybe Oracle will integrate this capability in mysql .... With 8GB databases, making a new copy should not give a lot of problems .... 15 minutes for a copy?

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I'll keep this in mind, if I find myself working with Oracle. :)